# JS: How do I effectively write code for multiple events on a single DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I am developing a game where I have the ability to dynamically on-the-fly generate skill buttons. When a player (for example) wants to update the skill "Strike", they click Upgrade Skills button and then strike. This pulls up a Radial Menu system where the user can then select 3 optional skills to upgrade to.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

I had to write this code 3 times because each position (1, 2 & 3) are each of the circle skills you see on the Radial.

The problem I'm having is with the event system. If I use .on('click'), ALL the skills get upgraded at the same time. So someone suggested I do this instead. .off('click').on('click').

The problem with that code was that position 1 & 2 got overwritten by position 3, since I was calling .off('click').

So I settled for .one('click')

However, this comes with a new unique and interesting problem.

Lets say for example, I want to upgrade skill strike and replace it with the skill on position1. I click on that and it works fine. No problem. But now lets say after doing that.. I want to upgrade my Defend skill and then click on the optional skill on position2 of the Radial. Well, the first click does nothing. Then clicking on it a 2nd time, it works and replaces it.

Effectively this makes the user have to double click to get a skill to upgrade, where as before, he only had to click 1 time on a skill to upgrade. I don't want my players to constantly double-click to upgrade there skills.

I know that perhaps where i'm having trouble is because i'm putting MULTIPLE events on 1 HTML dom element target. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you show your html please.

Comment: This might be happening for many different reasons. Please show us some HTML and CSS, preferably a working example.

Comment: Why are you delegating your click events if you are assigning them to elements with IDs? Do you have multiple elements with the same position IDs?